Google Sheets: Store a formula as a function to be called by multiple cells
I can't find this specific problem anywhere I look.
I have some formulas being used multiple times in my sheet. The seed data going into each use is different, but the function it performs is the same. But that means if I want to change the formula itself, I have to go to each cell that uses it and change it to match.
Is there a way to store this formula so I can call it from multiple cells and have it perform the function as if it were being called from /that/ cell?
Here's how one of the formulas works:
(L6*5)+((G4+G5)*2)+((G4*2)+(G5*2))
This is executed in cell M6, where L6=4, G4=5, and G5=3, giving me a result of 52.
So I want to create a function that takes 3 arguments, performs this formula, and returns the result.
Something like:
function(arg1, arg2, arg3){return (arg1*5)+((arg2+arg3)*2)+((arg2*2)+(arg3*2))}
But I can't figure out if it's even possible to essentially store a function in a cell like that.

Are the 'multiple cells' you refer to in your question actually columns of numbers in colL & ColG? If so this can be handled with a single array formula rather than require a named function to be created.

not in a single column

Create a Named function F from Data > Named functions with the following parameters: a,b,c and the following definition:
=a*5+4*(b+c)

Then you can use it as follows:
=F(L6,G4,G5)


